# Need permissions assistance with Samba share

Tags: linux, debian, samba

Running Samba 4.13.13 on Debian. I just created a new ext4 filesystem on a 1 TB external drive, mounted it, and am attempting to share it. In `smb.cnf`, I copied the section from the last filesystem, then changed the section (see below) name and `path`, saved the file, and restarted the `smbd` service with systemctl. Windows sees the share, and I can mount it (same user as all the other shares from my fileserver) but it doesn't have write permissions. It's not mounted read-only, and I can write to it as `root` from linux. What should I check?

Here is the relevant section of `smb.conf`:

```
[downloads]
path = /srv/downloads
guest ok = yes
guest only = no
read only = no
browseable = yes
inherit acls = yes
inherit permissions = no
ea support = no
store dos attributes = no
vfs objects =
printable = no
create mask = 0664
force create mode = 0664
directory mask = 0775
force directory mode = 0775
hide special files = yes
follow symlinks = yes
hide dot files = yes
read list =
write list =
```

Comment: There is no one in the write list and the mode is 775 so that no one other than the group and owner have modify permissions. Do the samba users who are trying to write to it at least have modify permissions on-disk?

Comment: But it's an exact copy of the previous file system (folder permissions match as well) which works just fine.

Comment: You said that it is a new external hard drive and you then created an ext4 filesystem on it and then copied the section from the last filesystem. Copying it doesn't always preserve the permissions and ownership especially when it's a new filesystem. If you used `rsync -av or cp --preserve-permissions`, then it did but you never specified that. Either way, the fact that users can't write to it and could before means that something is not the same. Is the external drive mounted at the directory? Have you verified the permissions of where the users are writing? Have you checked the logs?

Comment: OK, figured it out: I had group write on the main dir but not the subdir that I was trying to write to. Thanks.